# How to run a worker for certain duration of time in Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I am writing a rails app in which I have a piece of code which is dependent on Time zones.

How can make my Sidekiq worker, work only in day time of a time zone i.e. for a certain duration of time everyday.

The worker should pause at certain point of time (end of day) even when its queue is not empty and resume the next day.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting a Cron Job, using the whenever gem that stops the Sidekiq workers at a certain time, and starts them again at a certain time.

You can stop sidekiq workers via sidekiqctl:
sidekiqctl stop [pidfile] 60

Comment: I know Cron job solution, I wanted to know if I can do that in my script itself.